# Where Outlook log debug output

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook

I am developping an Outlook Addin with VisualStudio Pro 2015 with Outlook 2013. When i launch my ribbon with F5 it launch Outlook within VisualStudio and i can see Outlook output in VisualStudio console which is very usefull. For example :

```
'outlook.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain) : Chargé 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Impossible de trouver ou d'ouvrir le fichier PDB.
'outlook.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain) : Chargé 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Impossible de trouver ou d'ouvrir le fichier PDB.
'outlook.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain) : Chargé 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Security\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Security.dll'. Impossible de trouver ou d'ouvrir le fichier PDB.
'outlook.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain) : Chargé 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Deployment.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_fr_b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Deployment.resources.dll'. Le module a été généré sans symboles.
Exception levée : 'System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException' dans System.Deployment.dll
'outlook.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain) : Chargé 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'. Impossible de trouver ou d'ouvrir le fichier PDB.
Exception levée : 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' dans Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Hosting.dll
Le thread 0x1224 s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).
```

But when i launch Outlook outside VisualStudio i dont know where to find those log. I have enable global and advanced logging but the logs in %temp%\Outlook Logging folder are totally useless or unreadable and dont contain what i have listed above.

Do you have any idea how to make Outlook log what it seems to be its "debug output"

Kind regards,

Comment: Im not sure outlook would give you that level of logging.. https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2862843 doesnt mention any logging for plugins

Comment: You are right Outlook doesnt provide logging for plugin that why i have configure a logger in my plugin that output on a file i choosed. But in my example the output dont come from plugin but from Outlook core, If VisualStudio can display the debug output given by Outlook its meens that someone else (like a logger) could also read it and store it in a file...i guess.

Comment: but thats because its debugging outlook - you could attach a debugger to outlook..

Comment: @BugFinder ok but in those log there are also Fatal error (like outOfMemory error that made Outlook crash) that could be great to have in log file. Mostly because its hard to ask to a customer to plug a debuger everytime he launch Outlook, its easier to get a log file after crash.